# Encrypted UserName In GetRolesForUser RoleProvider

Tags: asp.net-mvc, encryption, asp.net-mvc-5, membership-provider, roleprovider

I Encrypt and Decrypt Data with Key and Iv,
and encryepted UserName.(create a key and iv for each user register on my site)
so i need to specify key and iv for decrypt each username

*GetRolesForUser* method in *RoleProvider*
only have one parameter (username)

```
public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
        {
            var roles = (from u in db.Users
                join r in db.Roles on u.RoleId equals r.Id
                where u.UserName == username
                select r.RoleNameInSystem).ToArray();
            return roles;
        }
```

Above code work fine but when data are not encrypted.

But for Decrypt username need to Key and Iv each user

I have no idea for solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, in controller i access to Key and Iv ,when user login on my site i encrypt user name and pass to `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie` ,The task of this method is send username to **RoleProvider** class (*GetRolesForUser* method).

***It is important to note that***: *User.Identity.Name* return Encrypted username